# List position of all windows

Tags: windows-7

I'm looking for a program that can list the position of all opened windows. I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate and have a multi-monitor setup.

Comment: List the position as in x/y coordinates? Width/height included?

Comment: yes, x/y+Width/height